# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command... during an npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp-sass

Totally new to node.js/npm, trying to get a couple new front-end tools under my belt. I'm on a windows box. I can do:

```
D:\Users\saturdayplace\Documents\www\accntr>node -v
v4.1.2

D:\Users\saturdayplace\Documents\www\accntr>which node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE

D:\Users\saturdayplace\Documents\www\accntr>echo %path%
< a bunch of stuff that includes C:\Program Files\nodejs\ >
```

And there's a node.exe in that folder. So, I'm fairly certain that my case is different from the typical, "Is it on your path?" or "Is node actually installed?" situations. I've `npm install`d a bunch of other things (including stuff that needs a C (or whatever) compiler), but for some reason, sass-gulp just don't wanna play nice.  Here's what it does:

```
D:\Users\saturdayplace\Documents\www\accntr>npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.0.3 should be installed with -g

> node-sass@3.3.3 install D:\Users\saturdayplace\Documents\www\accntr\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
accntr@0.0.0 D:\Users\saturdayplace\Documents\www\accntr
├─┬ gulp@3.9.0
│ └─┬ vinyl-fs@0.3.14
│   ├─┬ glob-stream@3.1.18
│   │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5
│   │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33
│   └─┬ through2@0.6.5
│     └── readable-stream@1.0.33
├─┬ gulp-concat@2.6.0
│ └─┬ through2@0.6.5
│   └── readable-stream@1.0.33
└─┬ main-bower-files@2.9.0
  └─┬ vinyl-fs@1.0.0
    ├─┬ merge-stream@0.1.8
    │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5
    │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33
    ├── object-assign@2.1.1
    └─┬ through2@0.6.5
      └── readable-stream@1.0.33

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp-sass" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v4.1.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.3.3 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.3.3 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: According to their FAQ, https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/wiki/Common-Issues-and-Their-Fixes, might be an issue with node sass.

Comment: That turned out to be the case. So I'd opened a ticket on their project. After a little troubleshooting, they asked me to upgrade my npm version, and that cleared up whatever was the problem.

Comment: had the same issue. `npm install -g npm` (`3.3.7` -> `3.5.3` the issue was solved somewhere between there)